# Proof about direct sum of vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $V$, a vector space above $\mathbb{F}$ and $W_1,...,W_n \subseteq V$, such that $V = W_1 + ... + W_n$. Prove that $V = W_1 \oplus \ldots \oplus W_n \iff $ for every $I,J\subseteq \{1\ldots n\}$ such that $I\cap J = \emptyset$ and $I\cup J = \{1\ldots n\}$: $$\text{span}\{ W_i \}_{i\in I} \cap \text{span}\{ W_j \}_{j\in J} = \{0\}$$

I've read that for the generalized case: $V = W_1 \oplus \ldots \oplus W_n \iff $ for all $i$ $W_i \cap ( W_1 \ldots W_{i-1} + W_{i+1} + \ldots + W_n) = \emptyset$ so maybe it can come handy here.

I'd be glad for guidance.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean $I,J\subset\{1,\ldots,n\}$?

Comment: Also, what is your definition for $W_1, …, W_n$ yielding an internal direct sum of $V$?

Comment: $W_1,\ldots,W_n$ are subspaces of $V$.

Comment: @AlonAlon … such that …? Finish the following sentence: “For subspaces $W_1, …, W_n$ of $V$, we say $V$ is the internal direct sum of $W_1, …, W_n$ – written $V = W_1 \oplus … \oplus W_n$ –, if …”

Comment: If for every $v\in V$ there's a unique sum $v = w_1 + w_2 + ... + w_n$ where $w_i \in W_i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say $V = W_1 \oplus … \oplus W_n$.

If there was a pair $I, J \subseteq \{1, …, n\}$ such that $I ∩ J = ∅$ and $I ∪ J = \{1, …, n\}$, but

$$\mathrm{span} \{W_i;~i ∈ I\} ∩ \mathrm{span} \{W_j;~j ∈ J\} ≠ \{0\},$$

you would be able to write $0 ∈ V$ in two different ways as a sum $0 = w_1 + … + w_n$ with $w_1 ∈ W_1, …, w_n ∈ W_n$. (There’s always a trivial one, but what’s the other one?)

---

Say the condition you have given holds.

Since $V = W_1 + … + W_n$, you can write any $v ∈ V$ as $v = w_1 + … + w_n$ for some $w_1 ∈ W_1, …, w_n ∈ W_n$. To show that this already is unique, it suffices to prove that $v = 0$ can be uniquely written as such a sum. (Why?)

So write $0 = w_1 + … + w_n$ with $w_1 ∈ W_1, … , w_n ∈ W_n$. Then
\begin{align*}
w_1 &= -(w_2 + w_3 + … + w_n), &\text{so}& &w_1 ∈ &W_1 ∩ \mathrm{span} \{W_2, W_3, …, W_n\}\\
w_2 &= -(w_1 + w_3 + … + w_n), &\text{so}& &w_2 ∈ &W_2 ∩ \mathrm{span} \{W_1, W_3, …, W_n\}\\
&… &\text{so}& &…&\\
w_n &= -(w_1 + w_2 + … + w_{n-1}), &\text{so}& &w_{n-1} ∈ &W_{n-1} ∩ \mathrm{span} \{W_1, W_2, …, W_{n-1}\}.
\end{align*}
Therefore …

(Yeah, or put otherwise: If your condition holds, then trivially the weaker condition holds that you have given. So you can already conclude the sum is direct.)

Comment: For the first case, suppose that $0\ne v \in \mathrm{span} \{W_i;~i ∈ I\} ∩ \mathrm{span} \{W_j;~j ∈ J\}$ then we could write $v-v = 0$. Right? ($v$ is both in some $W_i$ and some $W_j$)

Comment: Yes, and furthermore $v = \sum_{i ∈ I} w_i$ for some $w_i ∈ W_i$ and $v = \sum_{j ∈ J} w_j$ for some $w_j ∈ W_j$. Therefore $0 = v - v = \sum_{i ∈ I} w_i - \sum_{j ∈ J} w_j$. You now use $I ∩ J = ∅$ to conclude that this is really a sum of the needed form. (You even need to know that there is a $w_i ≠ 0$ and a $w_j ≠ 0$ in the sum.)

Comment: For the second part, Why is it suffice to prove it only for $v=0$? I don't get it

Comment: If there is some $v ∈ V$ with $v = w_1 + … + w_n$ and $v = w_1' + … + w_n'$, what’s $v - v$?